# Teapot signature/symbol/character

Tags: meaning, characters

Could anyone tell me what this symbol at the bottom of a teapot stands for? Thank you![This is a tea set I found in my mother’s house a few years ago]

[image]

Comment: I guess this says 王双華制

Comment: Cannot read a thing lol

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we would need to know the origin of the tea set and whether or not it originated in China at all. For all we know, this might be Japanese and isn't relevant to the Chinese language at all.

This photo is not clear and it isn't very impossible to verify what exactly is on your teapot. However, seeing that it is the Zisha variety, if it is in fact Chinese, there are three possibilities:

1. The maker or manufacturer's name: There is a high chance that it has the name of the person or company that made it, as Chinese teapots have been historically labelled as such.
2. The year in which it was made: Looking at the carvings, it seems unlikely that this is the year it was made. However, of course, the carvings could always reflect which year of a certain emperor's reign it was made (for example, 光绪三年, which is the third year of Emperor GuangXu's reign). I personally think that it is unlikely, as the teapot looks quite new.
3. A greeting or wish. Many artifacts of Chinese culture contain words of good meanings as engravings, like 福寿绵长, which hopes for good luck and good health.

I personally think that the first possibility is most likely, as this is what most modern manufacturers do now. They treat this engraving as sort of a brand label. However, as the photo is not clear and that the engraving is in Zhuan writing - an ancient writing style dating over 3000 years - the specific meanings are hard to decipher.

Anyhow, good luck!